# Value Error :shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape, in my code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to animate my time dependent curve, by storing each frame containg the curve at a certain time step,but caught up with this reoccuring error,
Below mentioned is my code for the same:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

fig=plt.figure()
l,=plt.plot([],[],'k-')

metadata=dict(title="Psi(x,t)",artist="Me")
writer=PillowWriter(fps=15,metadata=metadata)

xlist_t=[]
ylist_t=[]

with writer.saving(fig,"Psi(x,t).gif",100):
  for n in n_values:
    xlist_t.append(n)
    ylist_t.append(PSI[n])

    l.set_data(xlist_t,ylist_t)
    writer.grab_frame()
```

PSI is a multi dimensional array whose each row corresponds to a particular value of n

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plot` should be `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`....

Comment: also,  what `n_values` is undefined.

Comment: for the above two reasons alone, the code will not work.   Please send this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example